# How do you specify a different layout template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I've been working on an app that used the Angular phonecat app as a starting point.  I understand that the Angular phonecat app started with the AngularJS seed project.  My question seems simple, but have not been able to track down the answer so far:

How do you change the **layout template** from **index.html** to something else (*e.g. test.html*)?

I have my:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

in **index.html** and all my routing specified using **$routeProvider** and it is working fine, so I understand how to set up routing, but that's not my question.  What I don't know is how does angular knows to use the **index.html** file as the **layout template** which the partials get injected into.

The motivation for the question is that I would like to use a different **layout template** to experiment with.

Comment: EDIT: Just took a look at the phonecat/angularjs bootstrap repos. [Angular is bootstrapped from a base template via the `ng-app` tag (link to docs)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap). It looks like you're just directly hitting `index.html` in your browser. In which case if you wanted a different "base template" you could just make another template. As long as it has all the javascript links in there and an `ng-app` tag and `ng-view` directive somewhere, you should be fine.

Comment: The default `index.html` for both projects seems very sparse to begin with. (I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right projects or you've made major changes however.) If you wanted to change the "layout template" for the page, you could just make that styling in the partials that get injected in the `ng-view`. Most angular projects I've worked on, we try to keep the `index.html` as sparse as possible. Then just delegate the page styling to partials. You can devise a hierarchy so you have a "base.html" file that has your base page styling that every other page inherits from.

Comment: The code in our    index.html is sparse, and yes, you're right about the partials, but I'd like to know how **index.html** gets set as the **layout template** (*to use the Angular parlance*)

Comment: I found the reference to "layout template" inside [this step of the phonecat tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07). `index.html` is the root of the angular application because that's where the script tag with the angular.js file is located. Thus angular bootstraps inside `index.html`. Your app is thus bound to this base html file. Using `ng-view` enables you to switch out partials inside of it while staying inside the angular instance. If you want to use something other than `index.html` as your base, then you're effectively creating an entirely new angular app. That help?

Comment: Essentially, "layout template" in their explanation is just another way of referring to the base template that angular is bound to. The important difference being that instead of having just one template (`index.html`) with all the possible pieces of html inlined inside of it, you have an `ng-view` inside of this template that has the partials swapped out via angular.

Comment: I looked at the reference you provided and it didn't help.  My urls looks something like this: **http://localhost:8080/#/reports/listReportlets**  There are no direct references to **index.html** such as the tutorial mentions.  As an experiment, I changed the name from **index.html** to **_index.html** and as I expected, it broke everything.  Bottom line is that angular somehow magically knows that it should use **index.html** as it's **layout template**.  It appears to look for that file name specifically.

Comment: `index.html` in this case is just the file that the browser gets when you navigate to that URL. It's not a "special template" file. It is the HTML that is loaded into DOM by the browser. This is where `ng-app` directive is found.

Answer (score 0):

All my urls start with `http://www.localhost.com:8080/#/...` which the **web server** assumes to be `index.html`.  This is the logical place for angular to bootstrap from.  KhalilRavanna is right.  I wasn't fully groking his explanations.